# MonoTouch - Accelerometer with MotionManager stop sending updates

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, core-motion

I'm trying to use the accelerometer with `Monotouch` but a got an issue with `MotionManager`.
**Updates stop to be sent after 2-3 sec.**

Here is the code. (Everything is created in the constructor of my main `UIView`).

```
CMMotionManager motionManager = new CMMotionManager();
motionManager.AccelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.5;
motionManager
    .StartAccelerometerUpdates(NSOperationQueue.CurrentQueue, 
        delegate(CMAccelerometerData data, NSError error) 
{
    myLabel.Text = data.Acceleration.X.ToString("0.0000");        
});
```

With `UIAccelerometer`, it's working:

```
UIAccelerometer acc = UIAccelerometer.SharedAccelerometer;
acc.UpdateInterval = 0.5;
acc.Acceleration += delegate(object sender, UIAccelerometerEventArgs e) 
{
    myLabel.Text = e.Acceleration.X.ToString("0.0000"); 
};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough source code to see if you keep a reference to your `CMMotionManager` instance. Otherwise the GC could dispose of it, which would stop any update.

In comparison you are using the **shared** `UIAccelerometer` (which won't ever be GC'ed) while you're creating your own `CMMotionManager` (which could be).

Comment: I just tried to keep a reference on the MotionManager and it works. Thank you!